# SuSE Linux Enterprise 12: Difference between /etc/hostname and yast2 > Hostnames?

Tags: linux, hostname, suse

I'm right now setting up a new SuSE Linux Enterprise 12 server. Can somebody explain, what difference there is between `/etc/hostname` and yast2 > Hostnames? Both seem to have different contents and changes in one place do not seem to have an effect on the other place.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/hostname` contains the hostname which is applied to the system during startup. In other words - set the machine's name to the content of that file.

`yast2 > Hostnames` is used to add/delete/modify entries in the file `/etc/hosts`. This is some kind of a basic name resolution system and you can use it to map IP addresses to hostnames (and aliases).

Further reading:

```
man 1 hostname
man hosts
```

**EDIT:**

To change the contents of `/etc/hostname` see

yast2 -> System -> Network Settings -> Hostname/DNS.